# Explore the convergence of a series!

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln\left(\dfrac{n^4+3n^3}{n^4+1}\right)$$
using the characteristic comparison, to investigate the series for convergence.

Comment: If you would use MathJax, I would be able to help you, but I cannot see your image.

Comment: why not? click on the link((

Comment: Well, @Anastasia, go ahead and write down what you tried. As you might have noticed by the trend of you r previous questions, this site does not appreciate homework being dumped without effort.

Comment: @Anastasia because the site is restricted from my work's access

Answer (score 1):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function along with Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1} \tag 1$$

Using the left-hand side inequality in $(1)$, we can assert that

$$\log\left( \frac{n^4+3n^3}{n^4+1}\right)\ge \frac{3n^3-1}{n^4+3n^3}\ge \frac1{4n}$$

We conclude by comparison with the harmonic series that the series of interest diverges.